# how to enable a Rails gem on a specific server but not on others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to enable newrelic gem only on one of my servers but not on others which are part of cluster

Comment: have you put the servers on separate environments?

Comment: As @dax says, if you want to add a separate environment, you can clone existing environment files in the `config/environments` directory.

From there, if you want to load your special gem, you would use
`group :special_server { gem 'newrelic' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do this through some manipulation of the newrelic.yml.  For example, you could write a capistrano recipe that sets the monitor_mode = false for all servers in your production environment except for the one you want to enable.

Comment: Yes @steakchaser, this is what I've done in newrelic.yml: `agent_enabled: <%= ["hostname1", "hostname2"].include?(Socket.gethostname).to_s %>`